# Помогите определиться с выбором программы для графического интерфейса. чтобы совместить Python+XL

Tags: python

Планирую написать приложение (с графическим интерфейсом), которое будет принимать два файла xl. Один - с наименованием товара и ценой продажи, другой файл xl - с наименованием товара и себестоимостью. Идея в том, чтобы после загрузки в приложение, Python сравнил названия товара из таблиц, сопоставил названия, подставил себестоимость и по заданным мною формулам посчитал прибыль.

Я не знаю какие программы совместно с Питоном нужно использовать чтобы приложение получилось красивым, функциональным и кроссплатформенным.

Comment: Самым кроссплатформенным будет веб-сайт, например )

Comment: Спасибо) Т.е. на Django я могу реализовать вес. эту задумку?

Comment: А то меня уже понесло Pyside, pyQT5

Comment: Ну я не уверен, что всё остальное будет на любых платформах работать.